# MongoDB findBy..In vs FindBy..Containing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have some class Event:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "event")
public class Event {
private String id;
private List<Type> types;
}
```

Now I want to get all events that contain some Type instance in types. I can write two methods in MongoRepository class:

```
List<Event> findByTypesContaining(List<Type> type, Pageable pageable);
```

or

```
List<Event> findByTypesIn(List<Type> type, Pageable pageable);
```

and both are works. When I have to use ...Containing and ...In and what the difference between them?

Comment: what is Type? is it an enum?

Comment: I think it is can be an enum, in general. In my case, it is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries), you can see that,

`findBy...Containing` can be used on a collection or a String(to see if the given string is a substring)
whereas
`findBy...In` can only be used on a Collection.